# Succeed vs Successful

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives

I have this English sentence,

> The "XYZ" has been **successful** at mopping up the working-class vote.

Since I want to make sure that I've correctly understood the meaning of the two words (the verb succeed and the adjective successful), I would like to know if I can modify the sentence above and get the same meaning:

> "The XYZ" **succeeded** at mopping up the working-class vote.

Comment: Yep. I can't think of any difference in meaning (though I'm sure I'll be proven wrong shortly!)...

Comment: Only difference is that the first one indicates activity that might still be occurring, while the second one is in the past.

Answer (score 1):

> The "XYZ" has been **successful** [in] mopping up the working-class vote.

The above gives a sense that more actions would ensue.

OP's suggestion,

> The "XYZ" **succeeded** [in] mopping up the working-class vote.

however, is in the past tense and is more for describing a completed event.

The present perfect would be better:

> The "XYZ" **has succeeded** in mopping up the working-class vote.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct for the most part but there is a little difference between the two sentences. The first sentence indicates that the activity might still be ongoing therefore I would suggest:

> The "XYZ" **was successful** at mopping up the working-class vote.